# Rotate background image in JavaFX CSS

Tags: css, javafx

I'm using JavaFX with CSS. I have set up two Panes, one horizontal (600x200) and one vertical (200x600). I also have an image that is 600x200, and I want to put it as a background in both of the panes, but for the horizontal one the background has to be rotated.

Is there a way to rotate the background in CSS or directly in Java/FXML?

Comment: Nope, neither [`Background`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Background.html) nor [`BackgroundImage`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/BackgroundImage.html) support these kind of transformations and the CSS properties are only a different way of creating an `Background` object. You could of course create a snapshot of a rotated image, but imho this isn't really preferable to using a `ImageView`. (Also using a snapshot the images take twice as much of memory.)

Comment: @fabian so is there a workaround using imageviews and stackpanes? I don’t know how to center the rotated image view so that it perfectly fits the 600x200 pane

Comment: The `rotate` property by default rotates around the center of a node. A `ImageView` center aligned in a `StackPane` should remain center aligned, but may exceede the bounds of the nodes. If you want to prevent that, wrap the `ImageView` in a `Group`. As for the fitting: binding the `fit...` properties should work. If you set `managed` to `false`, the child is also ignored when determining the size constraints of the `StackPane`, but in that case you'd need to center the `ImageView` yourself...